# Can't get $(this) working in jQueryUI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, this

I'm trying to create a generic autocomplete script using jQueryUI. The autocomplete should work for every:

```
<input type='text' class='autocomplete' id='foo'/>
<input type='text' class='autocomplete' id='bar'/>
...
```

Now I'm trying to access 'foo' or 'bar' in the source function using $(this), but when alerting I always get 'undefined'.

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the intent? To choose a source based on the id of the selected autocomplete?

Comment: He wants to make a generic func to autocomplete whatever field id is passed in.

Comment: @Hollister, thanks, but that didn't clarify. Do you "help" like that often? Why does he need to choose the source based on the element the autocomplete is attached to? It sounds like he needs to create the codeblock once for each autocomplete element, or once for each type of codeblock. This is not how you do DRY, by putting an if block within a source control definition structure. It just makes for more complex code.

Comment: @drachenstern Using the ID of the input field I determine server side which values to return. Yes, this is a DRY attempt.

Comment: Do you "comment" like that often? Obviously, the autocomplete source list has to match the kind of data expected in a given element. He does this by passing in the id. Without seeing his complete design, I don't think it's warranted to comment on the DRY aspect. This is clearly a simplified example for our benefit.

Comment: @Hollister I thought it was quite evident from what he was doing that he was attempting DRY. And yes, I do. As for @bart I have found that personally and with most coders I know, DRY is found by writing a few blocks of code initially, then looking for the repeated parts. In this case, the jQueryUI autocomplete is not prepared to do what you want, and you'll end up repeating only a few things overall, given the information we've seen so far. Either make each one a separate block entirely, or do as suggested by @lee

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Setup autocomplete separately for each item in your selection, using a closure to hold a reference to the relevant element.  Something like the following:

```
$('input.autocomplete').each(function(i, el) {
    el = $(el);
    el.autocomplete({
        source: function(req, add) {
            var id = el.attr('id');
            alert(id);
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Alternative (edit)**

I don't see why there is such resistance to using `each()`: it works, the code is very clear and readable, and it introduces no issues with efficiency; but if you're determined to avoid `each()`, here's an alternative...

*PLEASE NOTE:  the following approach relies (a little bit) on the internals of jQuery Autocomplete, so I'd recommend the first option... but the choice is yours.

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: function(req, add) {
            var id = this.element.attr('id');
            alert(id);
        }
    });
});
```

That will work, at least until/unless they change the way the `source()` function is called from within the `autocomplete` plugin.

So, you have two options... something for everyone.

Comment: It may work, but I think that an each is bad form here. Looking at the source now to work out if there's a better option.

Comment: Just tested it and it does work. Not sure yet whether this is the best solution.

Comment: @bart ~ I know it works, I just think it's bad form. However, the bad form may be on your part, not on @lee's, if that makes sense. Will you answer my question above?

Comment: Without hacking the way the autocomplete interface is designed to work, this looks ok. If a hack is used, it would be more brittle than this.

Comment: @drachenstern, @bart:  There's no problem with using the `each()` -- IMHO, it makes it very clear what the code does, and it doesn't produce any undesirable side-effects.  That said, I've posted another option that doesn't use `each()`.  The second option *does* rely a little bit on the internals of jQuery Autocomplete, so I'd recommend the first option... but it's ultimately your choice.

Comment: Even I can't see what's wrong with using ```each()``` here. I'm using a legacy version of the ```autocomplete``` library, and using ```each()``` is the only option that works for me, since the library doesn't have the ```source()``` method.

Answer (score 3):

To access that input element you should be able to do the following:

```
$(this.element).val();
```

Of course, that just gets the value. You can access the other attributes like so:

```
$(this.element).attr('value'); // just another way to get the value
$(this.element).attr('id');
```

Also, suppose you want to access that element in the [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select), you can do that like so:

```
$(event.target).attr('value');
$(event.target).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally **this** is the answer. not *$('this')* or *$(this)* just **this**

Example:

```
$(".peoplepicker").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var url = "/data/myResource";

        var thisControl = this.element; // <<---

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata"
            },
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                thisControl.parent().parent().find(".srchstat").hide();    // <<===
                thisControl.parent().parent().find(".searching").fadeIn(); // <<===
            },
... [snipped]
```

Using `thisControl = this.element;` you can act on the target control later in the scope of thisControl. Like this:

```
thisControl.css("color","red");
```

or

```
thisControl.parent().parent().find(".searching").fadeIn();
```

I hope this helps. fwiw: this is how I have it working in my production app.

```
/* I am using: */
/*! jQuery v3.3.1 
/*! jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2020-02-03
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` will come from your newly created function and thus not work. Move your `id` declaration above `source` and it should work.

Comment: he can't put $(this) above the "source" as that would put it in the options list, not quite what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Marwelin is correct. 'this' will reference the newly created function you are nested within. This is easily fixable by creating the var `id` outside the function and using it within the function.