# more than one autocomplete on a page with one function?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

is there a way to have more than one autocomplete text field on a page, all with different data in the drop down but all use one function? i.e. not repeat the code below for each one?

I've tried using `$(this)` inside the  `$().autocomplete{}` but it doesn't like it. I was thinking i could have a hidden field with the controller destination in that holds all the results. Got it working for all but each input has the same results as it is working by class.

OR is there a better way to have multiple autocompletes each with different dropdown data?

```
 $(".ac_input").autocomplete(


  base_url + $(".ac_input").siblings("input[name=goto]").val(),
  {
        delay:10,
        minChars:1,
        matchSubset:1,
        matchContains:1,
        cacheLength:10,
        onItemSelect:selectItem,
        onFindValue:findValue,
        formatItem:formatItem,
        autoFill:false,
        maxItemsToShow:10
    }

);
```

Comment: Replacing delay:10 with delay:$(this).attr("x") should work?

Comment: I just meant this as an example for using $(this) which you said isn't working, thought you could have been placing it in the wrong place.

Comment: Ideally i would like to use $(this) to specify the url. I want to hold this in a hidden field next to the search input

Comment: Found a So answer that answers this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299022/cant-get-this-working-in-jqueryui-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can always build it yourself: The general idea is to keep all the data you want the autocomplete to display in a < ul > and hide the < li > elements that don't match what you've entered. After that, all you need is some positioning and styling and voila!

Here is an example of a page I've written.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    //Enable the autocomplete
    autocomplete_handle('#search_username', '#autocomplete_container');
 });

    /**
     * Turns a input/li set to an autocomplete pack
     * The li must contain all the elements that should
     * be displayed by the autocomplete block
     */
    function autocomplete_handle(input_field, ul_field){
            $(input_field).keyup(function(){
                    var typed = $(this).val();
                    var matches = [];
                    var autocomplete = $(ul_field).children();

                    $(ul_field).show();

                    for(var i=0; i<autocomplete.length;i++){

                            if($('a',autocomplete[i]).text().indexOf(typed)==0){
                                    $(autocomplete[i]).show();
                            }else{
                                    $(autocomplete[i]).hide();
                            }
                    }
            });

    }
```

**PHP**

```
<ul id="autocomplete_container" style="display: none;" class="autocomplete">

                            <?php foreach($all_users->result() as $user):?>

                            <li style="display: none;">
                                    <a href="javascript:;"><?php echo $user->username;?></a>
                            </li>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Styling for the autocomplete fields of the application*/
input.autocomplete, ul.autocomplete{
    width: 150px;
}

ul.autocomplete{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}


ul.autocomplete li{ 
    margin:0px 2px 0px 0px;
}

ul.autocomplete{
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: default;
}

ul.autocomplete a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.autocomplete a:HOVER, ul.autocomplete a:FOCUS {
    background: #dddddd;
    border: 1px solid #000;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```