# Remove autocomplete selected item from the list in asp.net and Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am in the biggest problem 
**PLEASE DONT REPORT MY QUESTION DUPLICATE BECAUSE I DID NOT GET ANSWER FOR ASP.NET IN GOOGLE.

I am using jquery Autocomplete textbox in asp.net using web service.
my code

```js
$('input.txtE').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "WebServices.asmx/GetNames",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ 'txtInput' : '" + request.term + "','userName':'" + userName + "'}",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                mydata = data.d;
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

                    return {

                        label: item.split('/')[0],
                        val: item.split('/')[1]
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    },
    multiselect: false,
    minLength: 1,
    delay: 0,
    select: function (e, ui) {
        $(hfId).val(ui.item.val);
    }

});
```

```
<input type="hidden" id="hfId"/>
```

And my API return data in array format

```
 ["Abhishek/128", "Abyss/71", "athansiah/53", "blvsian/138", "DesmondH/91", "destined2hold/62", "dnbdesigns/94", "Dvus_lotus/85", "gserranof/47", "Illusions/89", "isaacwu111/111", "js/39"]
```

**What I need if a user selected remove him from the autocomplete list so we can't select him again.**

Please help me to short out it.

Comment: Just send selected items to API server as AJAX request parameters, using `data` option. Then, on server side, exclude received items from response. Or it is possible to make the trick on client side within `success` handler.

Comment: Thank you for your response can you please let me know how i can filter user from client side?

Comment: Do you want to exclude from list only actual (current) input value or all values that was selected at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preparation

In first, you need to store setected values. It is possible by using a global variable, hidden input control or arbitrary data [associated](https://api.jquery.com/data/) with your control. In the following example I create an array that is associated with autocomplete control and then store selected values to the array:

```
$('#my-control').autocomplete({
  create: function( e, ui ) {
    // initialize array
    $(this).data('selected', []);
  },
  select: function( e, ui ) {
    // store unique selected values
    var selected = $(this).data('selected');
    if(!~selected.indexOf(ui.item.value)) {
      selected.push(ui.item.value);
    }
  },

  // another options here

});
```

Now it is possible to consider the selected values for list filtering.

#### Server-side solution

The best way is to filter the list on API server side, because it reduces transferred data amount. Just send the stored values through an AJAX request, using data option:

```
var $control = $('#my-control');
$control.autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({

      // some AJAX options

      data: {
        term: request.term,
        selected: $control.data('selected') // send stored values
      }
    });
  },

  // some autocomplete options here

});
```

Then you have to implement server-side filtration in accordance to `selected` query string parameter.
For example

```
public class AutocompleteSourceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult<IEnumerable<MyClass>> GetItems(
        [FromUri]string term, 
        [FromUri]int[] selected)
    {
        // Load data
        // Fliter by term substring
        // Exclude selected items
        // Return the result
    }
}
```

#### Client-side solution

Another way is to filter responded list on client side, using `success` AJAX callback. In my example I will use fake [online REST API server](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/). The server ignores the `term` field of query string, so I also have to implement it on client-side.

```js
$control = $('#my-input');
$control.autocomplete({
  create: function(e, ui) {
    $(this).data('selected', []);
  },
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data) {
        var items = data
          // filter by term
          .filter(function(user) {
            return ~user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase());
          })
          // exclude stored selected values
          .filter(function(user) {
            return !~$control.data('selected').indexOf(user.id);
          })
          // cast to an objects with label and value properties
          .map(function(user) {
            return {
              label: user.name,
              value: user.id
            }
          });
        response(items);
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  },
  multiselect: false,
  minLength: 1,
  delay: 0,
  select: function(e, ui) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $ctrl = $(this);
    
    var selected = $control.data('selected');
    if (!~selected.indexOf(ui.item.value)) {
      // store selected value
      selected.push(ui.item.value);
      // set label instead of value
      $ctrl.val(ui.item.label);
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="my-input" type="text">
```

Type `L` to the input control. The first item will be *Leanne Graham*, select it. Then clean the input field and type `L` again, there will no *Leanne Graham* in the dropdown menu. Select *Ervin Howell*, then clean the input field and type `L` again. There will be neither *Leanne Graham* nor *Ervin Howell* in the dropdown menu.

If you want to consider only current selected value, you could store only latest value instead of an array and modify the `success` callback and the `select` event handler.

Comment: @alexaznder. This is working great for me, but i have one issue when I am using the code for one text box its fine, but when I am using it for multiple textboxes it's showing me repetition after second selection. Can you please  HELP?

Comment: @Sunny, it is difficult to understand that you are trying to do. Please, provide the code using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or another online tool to clarify your problem. Also you could ask a new question with actual code and include a link to this topic to provide context.

Comment: @Sunny, if you will ask a new question, please, give me the link, I want to understand the issue.

Comment: Oh, @Sunny, I think the issue reason is described in [Can't get $(this) working in jQueryUI autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4299022/7914637) topic. Please, try the solution from these topic and let me know if it sovles your issue.

Comment: here is the link- https://jsfiddle.net/sunnyepixel/gehxfymt/
please fill all input field.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't have enogh reputaion to chat over stackoverflow.
This is correct-  if the "Leanne Graham" was selected in one input it should be removed from all inputs

Comment: ok, @Sunny . Is [the code](https://jsfiddle.net/gehxfymt/3/) what you want?

Comment: Yes, THANK YOU SO MUCH. :)

Comment: How i want to give you thanks , how i can give you guerdon/money/reward?

Comment: @Sunny, people should help each other ;) The Stack Overflow idea is an exchange of knowledge and experience. I have helped you and hope you will help anybody.

Comment: Yes That's right. This is the community for helping others.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove selected value from array  using jQuery.

```
x = jQuery.grep(x, function(val) {return val != Item;});
```